# dataTables Row Plugin grouping and Pagination in each group

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables

Working on datatables and everything seems great. I am using the rowplugin and it works great and showing me the grouping properly

Here is the code for that

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#mytable').dataTable({ "bLengthChange": false, "bPaginate": true})
        .rowGrouping({bExpandableGrouping: true});
    });
});
```

Now I am trying to create a pagination for each grouped row as my row can contain thousand of records.

Is there any way of making a change, i am looking at `fnRedraw`, but to me seems no fix.

Here is the fiddle for the above

http://jsfiddle.net/8hr1wa1g/